# How to group a multiple flatten columns in Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have this data with 3 different schemas:

```
(1, 12, 43) 
(1, 6, 20) 
(2, 8, 43) 
(2, 5, 13)`
```

I tried to group on $0 and, I got output as

```
(1, {(1,12,43), (1,6,20)})
(2, {(2,8,43), (2,5,13)}
```

How can we generate like,

```
(1, {12,6}, {43,20}) 
(2, {8,5}, {43,13})
```

Comment: I almost got it, I used the output(data8) I got earlier and wrote `final = foreach data8 generate $0, $1.$1, $1.$2;` I got output as `(1, {(12),(6)}, {43),(20)})`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For that you are going to need a nested foreach:

```
A = LOAD 'your_data' using PigStorage(',');
B = group A by $0;
C = foreach B {
    AUX = foreach A generate $1,$2;
    generate group, AUX;
}
```

That gives the following output:

```
(1,{(6,20),(12,43)})
(2,{(5,13),(8,43)})
```

The reason why you need the AUX relation inside the nested foreach is that by default, when you group in Pig, it includes the field you are grouping by inside the grouped bag as well, so you have it twice. That is what happened to you when grouping by `$0`. You need the nested foreach to remove that unwanted value.

Hope that helps!

**EDIT**

If you want each column to go to the same tuple, try this instead:

```
A = LOAD 'your_data' using PigStorage(',');
B = group A by $0;
C = foreach B generate $0, BagToTuple($1.$1), BagToTuple($1.$2);
```

This will generate:

```
(1,(6,12),(20,43))
(2,(5,8),(13,43))
```

If you need each of the groups to be inside a bag instead of a tuple, use the `TOBAG` function:

```
C = foreach B generate $0, TOBAG(BagToTuple($1.$1)), TOBAG(BagToTuple($1.$2));
```

which will generate:

```
(1,{(6,12)},{(20,43)})
(2,{(5,8)},{(13,43)})
```

However, you can never have a bag without tuples, since a bag is just a group of tuples. Therefore, it is impossible to have in Pig exactly what you requested:

```
(1,{6,12},{20,43})
(2,{5,8},{13,43})
```

You will need to use a tuple or a bag with tuples.

Comment: Thank you. This is helpful but I am sorry this is not exactly what I was looking. The data I gave has three diff columns caseid, supportid, ticketno all are int datatype. I want output in form (caseid, {(supportid1,supportid2), (ticketno1,ticketno2)})